# How to filter game objects based on a component's attribute?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]
I currently have a player "sense ability" that would detect nearby enemies through `Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll()`

Enemies have a component that carries general properties about them:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyProperties : MonoBehaviour
{
    public WorldColors color;
    public bool hookable;
    public bool isLast;
}
```

Now I want to filter those enemies in an array based on the attribute `hookable == true`

What I managed to do so far is to filter them based on the component:

```
public static void GetObjectsWithComponent(Transform srcTransform, float checkRadius, LayerMask checkLayers, Type myType)
{
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(srcTransform.position, checkRadius, checkLayers);
    Collider2D[] collidersWithComponent = Array.FindAll(colliders, collider => collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(myType, out Component component));
    // Collider2D[] collidersWithComponentAttribute = ??
}
```

```
private void Update()
{
    Sense.GetObjectsWithComponent(this.transform, checkRadius, checkMask, typeof(EnemyProperties));
}
```

how can I filter them further based on the bool `hookable == true`?

Comment: Can you explain what more you want to filter? Your code leaves a good bit to desire in the way of explaining what you're looking to accomplish. From my perspective simply using a `if hookable {}` seems sufficient. Not to many more ways you can filter a boolean value.

Comment: the idea was to make a general purpose static method that would filter based on whichever attribute the component has. I also intend to use this for: `if (color == WorldColors.Blue)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use C# generics and Linq to make your life easier...

```
public static IEnumerable<TType> GetComponentsWithAttributeInCircle<TType>(Transform srcTransform, float checkRadius, LayerMask checkLayers, Func<TType, bool> filter)
{
    Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(srcTransform.position, checkRadius, checkLayers);
    IEnumerable<TType> colliderWithComponentAttribute = colliders.Select(collider => collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TType>()).Where(component => component != null).Where(filter);
    return colliderWithComponentAttribute;
}
```

and in Update:

```
private void Update()
{
    var hookableEnemies = Sense.GetComponentsWithAttributeInCircle<EnemyProperties>(this.transform, checkRadius, checkMask, (EnemyProperties => EnemyProperties.hookable));

    foreach (var enemy in hookableEnemies)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

As a remark to your additional comment, Linq is already pretty generic and general purpose. If you learn to use it, you can set up simple filters like this in no time. And it works well with compile time types. If you want to do the same thing without compile time knowledge of the types you will have to use reflection.

Reflection is usually slow, and not easy to follow, so if you can stick to Linq and generics, you will probably do a lot better.

Comment: did you mean `collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TType>().Where(component => component != null)` instead of `collider.gameObject.GetComponent(myType))`?
    
    I can't seem to chain it with .`where` when I use `collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TType>().Where(component => component != null)`

Comment: Yes, indeed. `colliders.Select(collider => collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TType>()).Where(component=>component != null)`. `Select` should return `IEnumerable<TType>`

Comment: Alright, seems to be that I had a brackets issue.This works:
`colliders.Select(collider => collider.gameObject.GetComponent<TType>()).Where(component => component != null)`

Though no way of doing filtering based on the attribute inside the static method?

Comment: You can provide a filtering labda to your method, similarly to how Linq does it. Pass the function something like `(Func<TType, bool> filter)`, and add an extra `.Where(filter)` at the end of the Linq expression.

Comment: I would never hire a programmer that mentions Linq as a solution to anything. And definitely would sack a person that places this... this... JavaScript/JQuery peacock-like thing anywhere near the Update method (executed 60/s).

Comment: @Andrew Łukasik I agree this is not a good solution as it triggers a lot of allocations. I don't agree with you assessment of Linq though. It's a pretty interesting library, and any C# programmer can benefit from learning about it. It would have been more productive if you had offered the solution based on OverlapCircleNonAlloc

Comment: Hi @artcorpse. I'm sure it is useful in many contexts, looks very handy. But in specific situation of high-frequency executions it solves something temporally at best. As game will continue to grow, adding more objects and complexity to search patterns, so the cpu costs of this particular convenience. At one point project may easily become unplayable for this reason alone. I think your answer is ok but the question is wrong - you don't filter at all; you setup everything so filter operation isn't even needed.

Answer (score 0):

The method `FindAll` from the Array class is prototyped as follows :

`public static T[] FindAll<T> (T[] array, Predicate<T> match);`

So the second argument is actually a function, or lambda. The `match` parameter needs to return a boolean. If it returns `true`, it adds the element in the resulting array. If it returns `false`, it doesn't.

So you can use the `&&` operator in order to filter the component `EnemyProperties` **and** the `hookable == true`.

It would look something like this :

`Collider2D[] collidersWithComponent = Array.FindAll(colliders, collider => (collider.gameObject.TryGetComponent(myType, out Component component) && collider.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyProperties>().hookable == true));`